# Component-Wise Resolution of Forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors

When considering projectile motion, it is standard to resolve the $x$ and $y$ components of acceleration, and this greatly simplifies the analysis.

When considering the forces acting on a body, we consider the $x$ and $y$ components, and resolve them, or use them to frame equations that must be satisfied.

However, I am not sure why this is justified theoretically?
I know the x component does not affect the y and vice versa. (Because the two are perpendicular to each other).

Can I get the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Are you asking why $x$ is independent of $y$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am asking why x is independent of y. This potentially has something to do with linear independence of vectors, but my math there is rusty. 
Further, what if I were to resolve into two non-perpendicular directions. As far as I know, that would also work (though it would not be convenient to get answers).

Comment: Since it appears you think its justified theoretically to resolve acceleration into x and y components, why wouldn't you also think its justified theoretically to resolve the forces as well, since they are related to acceleration by a scalar (m) in Newton's 2nd law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force is a vector quantity, which means it has both magnitude and direction. The way we mathematically talk about a vector's direction is by resolving the vector into a linear combination of its underlying basis vectors. In most applications, it suffices to do this is terms of the simplest possible basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the 3-D Cartesian coordinates. Doing this explicitly yields, for example,
\begin{gather*}
\vec{a} = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{array} \right) = 1 \vec{x} + 2 \vec{y} + 3\vec{z} = 1 \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) + 2 \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) + 3 \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1\\ 2\\3 \end{array} \right)
\end{gather*}
where the $\vec{x}$, $\vec{y}$, and $\vec{z}$ vectors are the usual Cartesian basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$ (hat notation for unit vectors is not used here). The reason that this works, as you alluded to, is that the three vectors form a linearly independent spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^3$ (it might be a good exercise for you to prove this).

By contrast, we find the magnitude of a given vector by taking its dot product with itself and then taking the square root: $|\vec{a}| = \sqrt{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}}$. The reason this makes sense is because it generalizes the Pythagorean formula for distance from the origin,
\begin{gather*}
|\vec{a}| = \sqrt{\sum_j a_j^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{14}
\end{gather*}
in which $j$ runs over the basis vector components of $\vec{a}$ and we have used our example from above.

To bring this all home, imagine that we have some particle moving with only an $x$ component to its velocity. Suddenly, a force acting only in the $z$ direction acts on the particle, necessitating a change in velocity. Given that the force vector only has a $z$ component, and the particle velocity only has a $x$ component, does it even make sense that the two would get "mixed up" in any way? No, of course not. The force will only change the velocity in the direction in which it acts. Likewise, if the force has some component in the particle's direction and some components orthogonal to that direction, only the projection of the force onto a given axis will affect the motion along that particular axis; the $x$ component will only affect the $x$ component, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the equation-of-motion in coordinate free form:

$$ m\vec a = F = m\vec g$$

and then resolve it in Cartesian coordinates, where $\hat y$ is at an angle $\theta$ wrt to vertical:

$$ \ddot y = -g\cos\theta $$
$$ \ddot x = g\sin\theta $$

which aren't coupled. Then just pick $\theta=0$:

$$ \ddot y = -g $$
$$ \ddot x = 0 $$

Comment: As soon as air friction comes in the two directions are not anymore independent, since the friction  is proportional to |v| or v^2

Comment: @trula if the OP wants extra, OP has to ask explicitly: skin friction resistance, pressure drag,  Coriolis force et al, curvature of Earth/gravity/air pressure/LASP rate, Magnus effect, counter measures....

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I am asking why x is independent of y

Two vectors are independent of each other if and only if one vector projection into the other maps to zero vector. Or in terms of limits :

$$ \lim_{\alpha \to \pi/2} r \cos(\alpha) = 0 \tag 1$$

So this occurs in case pair of vectors are perpendicular to each other.
You can also check [Gram/Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) orthogonalization process.

Btw, perpendicularity ($\alpha = \pi/2$) condition may apply just for standard Euclidean geometry, i.e. Euclidean plane, in other more convoluted geometries this may not be the case. So my given vector independence definition based on zero vector projection map should be more general than perpendicularity check.